# Can not find zipconf.h when compile php7.0.1

Tags: php, libzip

I installed libzip-1.0.1, and when I am on make phase for installing php, it shows an error said zip.h can not find zipconf.h. Actually, libzip-1.0.1 has zipconf.h, but is not in the same directory with zip.h. It is under /libzip-1.0.1/lib/ziplib/include.

So i try to copy zipconf.h to libzip-1.0.1/include where zip.h is, or alter the zip.h file. In the zip.h, i change #include < zipconf.h > to #include < DIR/zipconf.h >, DIR is the path of zipconf.h.

But either of them help, and after i copy zipconf.h or alter zip.h file, the other error "can not find zip.h" comes up during the make phase.

How can i fix this, and compile php with libzip. I use the flag --with-libzip=DIR when confgure

Answer (score 1):

When running the configure you should use the flag "--with-libzip="
Then during compilation it should know where all your libzip files are.

Comment: Hi，thanks for your comment, i do use the flag "--with-libzip=DIR", DIR is the path where i installed libzip. At first, "zip.h" can be found, and it can not find "zipconf.h" cause "zipconf.h" is in another directory. So i try to copy zipconf.h to the directory where "zip.h" is, or later "zip.h", #include <PATH/zipconf.h>, PATH is the path of "zipconf.h". But after i tried these 2 ways, "zip.h" can not be found then